# Cluster two features in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have two sparse scipy matrix's, `title and paragraph` whose dimensions are `(284,183)` and `(284,4195)` respectively. Each row of both matrix's are features from one instance of my dataset. I wish to cluster these without a predefined number of clusters and then plot them.

I also have an array, `Y` that relates to each row. `(284,1)`. One class is represented by 0, the other by 1. I would like to color the points using this. How can I do this using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the skikit-learn Affinity propagation or Mean-shift libraries for clustering. Those algorithms will output a number of clusters and centers. To use the `Y` seems to be a different question because you can't plot the multi dimensional point on a 3D plane unless you do some import some other libraries.

Comment: Please comment if this isn't what you wan't because I can't comment on your post because atm not enough reputation.

Comment: Tesnorflow is one good library for visualising multidimensional points. Or you can use a dendrogram on the mean distance of the points.

Comment: Y is simply two classes, represented by 1 or 0. ie. if 1,color blue, if 0 color red.

Comment: My question is do you want this plot to look like? @user7347576

Comment: The answer that you are asking for is how to cluster in python. The simple answer is use the skikit-learn clustering mean shift or the Affinity propagation library like this ' x=affinitypropagation(title) x.fit()' and it's literally that simple but that isn't what it seems like all you need. This looks just like one of the problems I had for research I had to do. What I need to know is what data are you getting .I can help you with this but this isn't the place maybe a private message or something because a lot more that just a one answer needs to be answered for the problem that you have.